# On the maximal of polynomial at a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization

I faced this problem when I studied polynomial.

> Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ be a cubic polynomial with real
>   coefficients, and $p(5)+p(25)=1906$.
>
> Find the maximal value of $|p(15)|$.

I have no idea without using convex function, but we cannot claim the convexity of $p(x)$ since its coefficients are real numbers only. This problem were in a Purple Comet Math Contest but I don't remember exactly the year.

Please help me to solve it,

Thanks.

Comment: $p(x)$ is  a convex function on $I=(\frac{-b}{3a}, \infty)$ if $5, 25\in I $ then $$f\left(\frac{5+25}{2}\right)\le \frac{f(5)+f(25)}{2}$$

Comment: what do we know about $$a,b,c,d$$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $p$ is any real cubic polynomial satisfying $p(5) + p(25) = 1906$. For any real $n$, let $q(x) = p(x) - n(x-5)(x-25)$. Now $q$ is also a real cubic polynomial satisfying $q(5)+q(25) = p(5)+p(25) = 1906$, but $q(15) = p(15) + 100n$.

Hence the value of $p(15)$ is not bounded, but can be any real number if you choose the coefficients properly.